# Find efficient seating arrangement in a line

Tags: math, code-challenge

We have X Girls and Y Boys in a class. If more girls sit together they will not behave. Similarly if more boys sit together they will not behave.

Write a program/algorithm to get maximum same gender that will be seated if seating is done to efficiently to get them behave.

Example 1: 5 girls and 1 boy
Expected Output: 3
Explanation: G G B **G G G**

Example 2: 7 girls and 3 boys
Expected Output: 2
Explanation: **G G** B G B G G B G G

Comment: Is this just `ceil(max(b,g)/(1+min(b,g)))`?

Comment: Maybe this should be `code-golf`?

Comment: This definitely doesn't seem complicated enough for [tag:fastest-algorithm] to be all that interesting, but it could be interesting to golf. There might even be the potential for some sort of thematically appropriate semi-golf [tag:code-challenge] scoring scheme, but that would probably be a bad idea.

Comment: what's the winning criteria? It would probably be best to do [tag:code-golf]

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 26 bytes

```python
lambda b,g:-min(b/~g,g/~b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSFJJ91KNzczTyNJvy5dJ12/Lknzf0FRZl6JQpqGoY6pJheMY65jjMwxQHAMUDlIykx1TJA5ppr/AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 31 bytes

*Port of [@TFeld python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/182605/78039)*

```javascript
a=>b=>-Math.min(a/~b,b/~a)+.5|0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/R1i7J1k7XN7EkQy83M08jUb8uSSdJvy5RU1vPtMbgf3J@XnF@TqpeTn66RpqGqaaGoaYmF6qguaaGsabmfwA)